# How to detect the presence of a hardware back button from a webapp with javascript

Tags: javascript, android

I've seen multiple questions regarding how to check the presence of a back button in Android, but they all seem to be geared towards apps in Android, which I don't believe would help here.

I want to determine the need to show a back button in a webapp that will be run across multiple OS's, and I know with javascript you can check what OS the device is, which answers the need to show or not show a back button for iOS, or Windows Phone, but with Android, since there's many different button set ups, I would like to be able to check the presence of either a software back button (like an LG, OnePlus One or something) or a hardware back button you would see on most other devices with hardware buttons.  I can't seem to find an answer in my searches, and if it's not possible, that's fine, I just want to ask and be sure.  Again, any answers need to be relevant to javascript solutions.  If there are any useful libraries or tools I can integrate in with the javascript, (i.e. something in angular, jquery, etc. then I'm happy to entertain those solutions as well).